# Foreign Key Unable to Add

Tags: mysql

I am try to add foreign key

```
CREATE TABLE `uniform_product_details` ( 
  `upc_id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
  `product_id` int(11),
  `condition_id` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `status`  INT NOT NULL,
  `created_by` VARCHAR(32), 
  `updated_by` VARCHAR(32),
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`upc_id`),
  INDEX `pid` (`product_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY(`product_id`) REFERENCES product(`product_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

but my Toad showing an error while doing this

> MySQL Database Error: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Is there any logical mistake I am caring with this Query. Help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it has to do with the Engine... MyISAM tables do not support foreign keys. Define the engine as InnoDB:

```
create table uniform_product_details(
    -- All your column definitions
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

You may need to change the engine for other tables. If that's the case, use this:

```
alter table another_table ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The full sequence of the solution might be as follows:

1. Create the tables *without* foreign key definitions
2. Alter all your tables: Set the engine to InnoDB for all of them
3. Add the foreign key definitions with:

   `alter table any_table add foreign key ...`;

---

Further reference about MySQL Storage Engines:

- [MySQL Reference Manual: Storage engines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-engines.html)

Comment: Engine is the cause. Can you please share some useful link to know more about this (engine). Just a request.

Comment: I am restricted to change my db engine instantly. But Yes I got the reason of the bug. Thanks for the help! As soon as i will got some required badges .. i will mark this as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
CREATE TABLE `uniform_product_details1` ( 
  `upc_id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
  `product_id` int(11),
  `condition_id` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `status`  INT NOT NULL,
  `created_by` VARCHAR(32), 
  `updated_by` VARCHAR(32),
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`upc_id`),
  INDEX `pid` (`product_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY(`product_id`)  REFERENCES product(`product_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```